# How can I download a whole gallery of images using wget?

Tags: linux, wget

There is a gallery in the format:

`http:\\DOMAIN\file0001.jpg` ⇒ `http:\\DOMAIN\file0543.jpg`

How can I download them all using `wget`?

How can I make it wait 2 seconds between downloads?

i'm using bash ver 3.2.

Comment: FYI, URLs use forward slashes (`http://domain/`), *never* backslashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash:

```
for ((i=1; i<=500; i++)); do wget http://DOMAIN/file`printf "%04d" $i`.jpg; done
```

If you want to wait 2 seconds between downloads, add a `sleep 2;` before the done

Answer (score 2):

Use ranges with `{..}`.

> `$ wget http://example.com/file{0001..0543}.jpg`

The above answer works with `zsh` and `bash` [version 4 and above](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace#new_in_bash_40). See the answer posted by @w00t if you're using an older version of bash (`bash -version` to check).

[image]

Comment: That doesn't keep the starting 0s

Comment: Cool, didn't know that. Now for the long wait until all bashes are v4 :-)